# Convert string to 4 byte array

Tags: java

Is it possible?

I am trying to conver a string to a 4byte array.

I saw a way of doing so with integer:

```
int i =55555;
ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array();
```

Cant find a way with String.

Comment: "Is it possible?" In general no. Only short strings can be represented in 4 bytes. It depends on the character set and on the encoding which strings can be represented.

Comment: By "converting a string to a four byte array", are you talking about something along the lines of taking the first four ASCII characters (or two Unicode characters) and converting them to their byte counterparts?

Answer (score 4):

Whats wrong with `"5555".getBytes();`

or if you only want the first 4 bytes

`"5555555".substring(0, 4).getBytes();`

Comment: Depends on how you want your bits representation using ByteBuffer is more appropriate for this task

Comment: Substring gets the first 4 chars (in whatever encoding), not bytes. Like this you could as well end up with 8 bytes.

Comment: Since this uses the default platform encoding, it will not always deliver 4 bytes